# How to use data generator to generate data faster while training keras model?

Tags: python, keras, training-data, data-generation

I followed [this tutorial](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly.html) to create the following data generator. However, it takes too much time for training. How can I make it run faster knowing that I have already created all the data files read by the `reader` object?

**ps**: The method `__data_generation` performs 2 disc access per iteration.

```
import numpy as np
import keras

class DataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):
    """
    Generates data for Keras
    :return: data generator object
    """
    def __init__(self, reader, list_IDs, labels, relations_list, batch_size=32, shuffle=True):
        # Initialization
        self.reader = reader
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.labels = labels
        self.list_IDs = list_IDs
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.on_epoch_end()
        self.relations = relations_list
        self.data_num = 0

    def __len__(self):
        """
        Denotes the number of batches per epoch
        :return: int
        """
        return int(np.floor(len(self.list_IDs) / self.batch_size))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        """
        Generate one batch of data
        :param index: index of the current training item
        :return: tuple
        """
        # Generate indexes of the batch
        indexes = self.indexes[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]

        # Find list of IDs
        list_IDs_temp = [self.list_IDs[k] for k in indexes]

        # Generate data
        X, y = self.__data_generation(list_IDs_temp)

        return X, y

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        """
        Updates indexes after each epoch
        :return:
        """
        self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.list_IDs))
        if self.shuffle:
            np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)

    def __data_generation(self, list_IDs_temp):
        """
        Generates data containing batch_size samples'
        :param list_IDs_temp: the list of IDs of the target batch
        :return: tuple
        """
        # Initialization
        y = []
        v_q_words = []
        v_d_words = []

        # Generate data
        for i, ID in enumerate(list_IDs_temp):
            # Store sample
            q_words = self.reader.get_query(self.relations[ID][0])  # corresponds to 1 file read from disc
            v_q_words.append(q_words)
            d_words = self.reader.get_document(self.relations[ID][1])  # corresponds to another file read from disc
            v_d_words.append(d_words)
            # Store class
            y.append(self.labels[ID])

        X = [np.array(v_q_words), np.array(v_d_words)]

        return X, np.array(y)
```

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [your link](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly.html)

> Since our code is multicore-friendly, note that you can do more complex operations instead (e.g. computations from source files) without worrying that data generation becomes a bottleneck in the training process.

As suggested by [@nabiltos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51382224/1545917), the most effective way to speed up your training is to use a GPU version of your `Keras` [backend](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#tensorflow_gpu_support), which implies to have a compatible GPU device installed on your machine.

Once installed, running this code should list your workstation GPUs

```
>>> from keras import backend as K
>>> K.tensorflow_backend._get_available_gpus()


name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.582
pciBusID: 0000:0b:00.0
totalMemory: 10.92GiB freeMemory: 10.32GiB
2018-07-17 14:09:36.190143: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1212] Found device 1 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.582
pciBusID: 0000:13:00.0
totalMemory: 10.92GiB freeMemory: 10.54GiB
2018-07-17 14:09:36.395138: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1212] Found device 2 with properties: 
name: TITAN X (Pascal) major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.531
pciBusID: 0000:1b:00.0
totalMemory: 11.91GiB freeMemory: 11.54GiB
2018-07-17 14:09:36.395451: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1312] Adding visible gpu devices: 0, 1, 2
2018-07-17 14:09:37.394013: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:993] Creating TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 9990 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:0b:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2018-07-17 14:09:37.563166: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:993] Creating TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1 with 10203 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 1, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:13:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2018-07-17 14:09:37.735253: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:993] Creating TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:2 with 11170 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 2, name: TITAN X (Pascal), pci bus id: 0000:1b:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
['/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0', '/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1', '/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:2']
```

You can see here that I have 3 GPU devices on my machine (2 x GeForce GTX 1080 Ti & 1 x TITAN X (Pascal)). If a TensorFlow operation has both CPU and GPU implementations, the GPU devices will be given priority ([read more](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu))

Comment: Thanks, @Ghilas I tried this code using CPU machine with SSD hard disc. I'll use a computation cluster with 4GPUs and 10,95GB memory limit per job, when I run the code on the CPU machine with SSD, it occupates 10.5GB, so my question: is it possible to run with 10.5GB occupated or not?

Comment: @BelkacemThiziri not sure if I've completely understood your point. but a GPU has a memory too. See my logs above and you'll find the `totalMemory` and `freeMemory` values for each GPU. So if you don't have an outrageously large model, it will probably fit on your 4 GPU cluster.

Comment: Okay, I'll check the cluster total memory of the 4 GPUs and try to run my code on this cluster, if it doesn't fit on its memory, I'll have to find the way to generate data in another way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should parallelize the data reading and your algorithm on GPU. 
As tensorflow is known for its speed on GPU cards it would be better to use the keras module which is included in tensorflow.

Comment: Thanks, @nabiltos for your response. Could you give a reference to an example, please?