# Fast Data Generator for Training GoogLeNet model

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I try to train GoogLeNet from scratch in Keras. I build the network architecture, and it is ready to train. Train GoogLeNet with auxiliaries outputs, the data generator should have three output labels. I write my custom data generator using `tf.keras.utils.Sequence`.

My custom generator is:

```
from skimage.transform import resize
from skimage.io import imread
import numpy as np
import math
from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence


class GoogLeNetDatasetGenerator(Sequence):

    def __init__(self, X_train_path, y_train, batch_size):
        """
        Initialize the GoogLeNet dataset generator.
        :param X_train_path: Path of train images
        :param y_train: Labels of train images
        :param batch_size:
        """

        self.X_train_path = X_train_path
        self.y_train = y_train
    self.batch_size = batch_size

        self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.X_train_path))
        np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)

    def __len__(self):
        """
        Denotes the number of batches per epoch
        :return:
        """

        return math.ceil(len(self.X_train_path) / self.batch_size)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        """
        Get batch indexes from shuffled indexes
        :param index:
        :return:
        """

        indexes = self.indexes[index * self.batch_size:(index + 1) * self.batch_size]
        X_batch_names = [self.X_train_path[i] for i in indexes]
        y_batch_naive = self.y_train[indexes]

        X_batch = np.array([resize(imread(file_name), (224, 224) for file_name in X_batch_names],
                       dtype='float32')
        y_batch = [y_batch_naive, y_batch_naive, y_batch_naive]

        return X_batch, y_batch

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        """
        Updates indexes after each epoch
        :return:
        """

        self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.X_train_path))
        np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)
```

Also, I compile and train the model with the following codes:

```
# Compile model
model.compile(loss=[CategoricalCrossentropy(), CategoricalCrossentropy(), CategoricalCrossentropy()],
                  loss_weights=[1, 0.3, 0.3], optimizer='adam',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train model
history = model.fit(train_dataset, validation_data=test_dataset, epochs=100)
```

While using the GPU version of TensorFlow, loading images in the data generator is time-consuming. It causes the training process slow. Is there any suggestion or other solutions for speeding up the loading data?

P.S.
I search the StackOverflow question such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51381329/how-to-use-data-generator-to-generate-data-faster-while-training-keras-model), but I did not find any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another faster solution. You can use `tf.data.Dataset`. In the first step, I list all training images directory. Using the `map` method helped me read the image and properly configure the corresponding label. Here is my sample code to load an image with the ternary label.

```
image_filenames = tf.constant(image_list)

slices_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(image_filenames)
slices_labels = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(label_list)

image_dataset = slices_dataset.map(map_func=process_image)
label_dataset = slices_labels.map(map_func=process_label)

x_dataset = image_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=Cfg.BUFFER_SIZE, seed=0).\
    batch(batch_size=Cfg.BATCH_SIZE)
y_dataset = label_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=Cfg.BUFFER_SIZE, seed=0).\
    batch(batch_size=Cfg.BATCH_SIZE)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((x_dataset, y_dataset))
```